# Disappearing items on DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown, autopostback

I'm having an issue with a DropDownList dispaying student names. For some reason it loses items after I click a button, which is used for giving them a grade. I'd like to find a way to preserve these items. The button does not, in any way, filter the students displayed. The resulting DropDownLists should also have autopostback set as true. The student names are not retrieved or altered in the code behind so I'm unsure why the names are disappearing from this DropDownList. Any hints/solutions would be welcome. Update: I have attached code from the front end and also code from the .cs file for the button that sends the mark for the student. After entering a score and going back to the module it was entered for the items disappearing problem arises.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="SQLStudentList" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UniString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT  students_profile.user_id, (first_name + ' ' + last_name ) AS studentDetails FROM students_profile  INNER JOIN classlist ON students_profile.user_id = classlist.user_id INNER JOIN class ON class.class_id = classlist.class_id INNER JOIN student_module_grade ON classlist.classlist_id = student_module_grade.classlist_id INNER JOIN student_module_repeat_grades ON student_module_grade.classlist_id = student_module_repeat_grades.classlist_id WHERE class.pathway_year_id = @idpathway AND  student_module_grade.module_on_pathway_id  =@modpwayid OR student_module_repeat_grades.module_on_pathway_id=@modpwayid">

  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="idpathway" ControlID="degreeProgDropDown" Type="String"/>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="modDropDown" Name="modpwayid" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList ID="StudentsList" 
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="StudentsList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
  runat="server" 
  width="420" 
  AutoPostBack="true" 
  EnableViewState="true"
  DataSourceID="SQLStudentList" 
  DataTextField="studentDetails" 
  DataValueField="user_id">
</asp:DropDownList>


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    ////If there are no students the message below will be displayed
    ListItem selectedItem = StudentsList.SelectedItem;
    if (selectedItem != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedItem.Text))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        changedFlag.Visible = true;
        changedFlag.Text = "There are currently no grades to change for any students for this module on this pathway";
        changedFlag.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        EnterFinalMark.Visible = false;
        finalMarkAssignment.Visible = false;
        submitAssignmentMark.Visible = false;
        repeatSubmitAssignmentMark.Visible = false;
    }
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        StudentsList.DataSource = SQLStudentList;
        StudentsList.DataBind();
        String userName = Session["UserLoggedOn"].ToString();

        String conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UniString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(conString);

        myCon.Open();


        String pathwaySelectionQuery = "SELECT pathway_years.id, pathway_years.pathway_year, pathway FROM pathways INNER JOIN pathway_years ON pathways.id = pathway_years.pathway_id";
        SqlCommand pathwaySelectionQuerycmd = new SqlCommand(pathwaySelectionQuery, myCon);
        SqlDataReader pwayReader = pathwaySelectionQuerycmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (pwayReader.Read())
        {
            //Put pathway year id in this table instead
            degreeProgDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem(pwayReader["pathway_year"] + ": " + pwayReader["pathway"].ToString(), pwayReader["id"].ToString()));


        }


        myCon.Close();

    }
}

    protected void repeatSubmitAssignmentMark_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UniString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    myConnection.Open();
    String repeatModgradeID = "SELECT repeat_module_grade_id from student_module_repeat_grades WHERE module_on_pathway_id = '" + modDropDown.SelectedValue + "'";
    SqlCommand repeatModuleGradeIDCommand = new SqlCommand(repeatModgradeID, myConnection);

    Int32 repeatModGradeIDResult = Convert.ToInt32(repeatModuleGradeIDCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    String repeatFindUserID = "SELECT classlist_id from classlist WHERE user_id = '" + StudentsList.SelectedValue + "'";
    SqlCommand repeatFindUserIDCommand = new SqlCommand(repeatFindUserID, myConnection);

    Int32 repeatClasslistval = Convert.ToInt32(repeatFindUserIDCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    String modOnPwayValue = modDropDown.SelectedValue;
    String repeatGrade = finalMarkAssignment.Text;
    Int32 repeatGradeval = Convert.ToInt32(repeatGrade);
    //Grade is a pass if it is equal to or greater than 40- otherwise it is a fail
    if (repeatGradeval >= 40)
    {
        //Pass assigned to the string which will be added to the table
        String passOrFail = "Pass";
        //Assigned to label
        pOrF.Text = passOrFail;

    }
    else
    {
        //Fail assigned to the string which will be added to the table
        String passOrFail = "Fail";
        //Assigned to label
        pOrF.Text = passOrFail;
    }
    if (repeatGradeval >= 0 && repeatGradeval <= 100)
    {
        changedVAL.Visible = false;
        SqlCommand addAssignmentGradeCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE student_module_repeat_grades SET classlist_id=@repeatClasslistid,module_on_pathway_id=@modOnPwayValue,grade=@grade,result_code=@PF,changed=1 WHERE module_on_pathway_id = '" + modDropDown.SelectedValue + "'", myConnection);
        addAssignmentGradeCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"modOnPwayValue", modOnPwayValue);
        addAssignmentGradeCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"repeatClasslistid", repeatClasslistval);
        addAssignmentGradeCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"grade", repeatGradeval);
        addAssignmentGradeCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"PF", pOrF.Text);
        addAssignmentGradeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
        success.Visible = true;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "HideLabel();", true);
        success.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        repeatSubmitAssignmentMark.Visible = false;

    }
    else
    {
        changedVAL.Visible = true;
        changedVAL.Text = "Please enter a grade between 0 and 100";
        changedVAL.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a possible guess from a common mistake I used to do in the past. Ensure things which need to happen only once on Page_Load is inside if(!IsPostback) { ... }. Or actually, why don't you move the codes to happen on Page_Load event? I don't particularly fancy the idea of using the UI to set the queries. Rather, I execute those queries and bind the results exactly when I want it to happen (in this case, maybe on Page_Load).

Comment: @spiros try to check where you are filling your dropdown code

Comment: @Webruster The DropDown data is from the front end only and changes according to the values in the other two DropDowns I have

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509676/gridview-loses-data-during-postback helpful?

Comment: @Spiros post your `.CS` Code

Comment: @spiros  You shouldn't need to set your datasource and call the databind event in you c code because you are already doing so in the aspx code with this line DataSourceID="SQLStudentList"  This will happen automatically on the page load.  I'm thinking just remove these lines StudentsList.DataSource = SQLStudentList; StudentsList.DataBind();

Comment: @JSON I originally had my code without the databind event and just had the aspx code but I was losing items in the students list. I'm trying to figure out how to avoid that happening.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought it that you are likely not currently checking if a `PostBack` is occurring or not within the `Page_Load` event of your Page, which is going to cause your data to be rebound each time.

You can generally resolve this by just performing a check within the `Page_Load` event itself :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // If it is an initial load
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {
         // Then perform your one-time data binding here
         StudentsList.DataSource = SQLStudentList;
         StudentsList.DataBind();
     }
     // Business as usual
}
```

Comment: Hi there, when I put StudentsList.DataSource = SQLStudentList;
            StudentsList.DataBind(); in the check if postback method I don't get any results in the dropdown. In my front end this DropDownLists depends on the selected values from the other two DropDownLists. They are populated with data,

Comment: If you are performing the `DataBind()` call (and previous setting of the data source) within the if-statement, then the code should be working as expected. Do you have any other code besides that?

Comment: Are you doing anything special within your Button Click events? If you were somehow performing a Redirect call to the current page, then it would trigger a `GET` request rather than a `POST` and you would lose your current values (as it would simply see it as another initial load).

Comment: I have a button that updates a table with a value the user enters but my problem now is that no students are appearing in the dropdown upon loading the page.

Comment: I have SelectedIndexChanged for the modules and year which this dropdown depends on if that information is helpful at all. Thanks for the help so far but I still can't get it working.