# Put data from a column Database into a combobox as a result

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview, combobox

I've made an application that allow a user to add data into a database by the way of a datagridview (which is made of column and a combobox). I've code the app to refresh the datagridview when the user click on the button and when the data are send to the database. After the refresh, the datagridview have his empty columns fills with the precedent user filled-data. It works for columns but not my combobox. I would like, after the refresh, the combobox to select the item that have been previously insert in my database (the combobox is a list of items already existing that the user can select to add to the DB).

Code of my button:

```
 private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
        maConnexion.Open();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {


            if ((row.Cells[20].Value != null) && (bool)row.Cells[20].Value)
            {

                SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();


                command = new SqlCommand("update FailAndPass set Machine=@machine, ProgCode=@pc, BoardName=@BName, BoardNumber=@BNumber, Tester=@T, DateTest=@DT, TimeTest=@TT, TimeStart=@TS, FComponent=@FC, Message=@Mess, TotalTestProg=@TTP, ReadValue=@RV, ValueReference=@VR, PTolerance=@PT, FaultDetail=@FD, RepairingDate=@RD, RepairingTime=@RT, ReportingOperator=@RO, FaultCodeByOP=@FCBO  WHERE SerialNum=@Serial", maConnexion);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", row.Cells[1].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial", textBox1.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pc", row.Cells[3].Value != null ? row.Cells[3].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BName", row.Cells[4].Value != null ? row.Cells[4].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BNumber", row.Cells[5].Value != null ? row.Cells[5].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T", row.Cells[6].Value != null ? row.Cells[6].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT", row.Cells[7].Value != null ? row.Cells[7].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TT", row.Cells[8].Value != null ? row.Cells[8].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TS", row.Cells[9].Value != null ? row.Cells[9].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FC", row.Cells[11].Value != null ? row.Cells[11].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mess", row.Cells[10].Value != null ? row.Cells[10].Value : DBNull.Value);                   
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TTP", row.Cells[12].Value != null ? row.Cells[12].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RV", row.Cells[13].Value != null ? row.Cells[13].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VR", row.Cells[14].Value != null ? row.Cells[14].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PT", row.Cells[15].Value != null ? row.Cells[15].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FD", row.Cells[16].Value != null ? row.Cells[16].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RD", row.Cells[17].Value != null ? row.Cells[17].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RT", row.Cells[18].Value != null ? row.Cells[18].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RO", row.Cells[19].Value != null ? row.Cells[19].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FCBO", row.Cells[20].Value != null ? row.Cells[20].Value : DBNull.Value);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();




            }
        }

        maConnexion.Close();
        this.Hide();
        Admin admin = new Admin();
        admin.Show();
    }
```

Database : 
[image: Pics]
Application :
[image: pic]

Thanks!

Comment: Check this out: [GridView loses data during postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509676/gridview-loses-data-during-postback) or [GridView.DataSource is null during PostBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931784/gridview-datasource-is-null-during-postback)

Comment: @RigertaDemiri, question is about Winforms DataGridView control. ASP.NET doesn't have `DataGridView` control.

Comment: I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

You need provide data for combobox items and configure combobox to "link" selected item with value from row.

```
var failCodes = new List<string>
{
    "Fail one";
    "Fail two";
    "Fail three";
}

comboboxColumn.DataSource = failCodes;
comboboxColumn.DataPropertyName = "FailCodeByOP"; //will select item with same value
```

Comment: But how he is gonna select the item that have been update in the database ?

Comment: @AlexisRin, item will be selected automatically by value from column you defined as `DataPropertyName`. In your case when `FailCodeByOP = 1` `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` will try display item which have `Code = 1`, if such item doesn't found in `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource` empty cell will be displayed

Comment: It doesnt work. It dont like <failcode> because it doesnt exist. Should i replace it by my list in my combobox or <string>?

Comment: @AlexisRin, `FailCode` was an example. Use your own list or use lists of strings if `FailCodeByOP` is string too. IN case you are using strings you don't need `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`

Comment: Doesnt work. Now my combobox have : Fail one, two, three. In my code i already had datapropertyname, and datasource with my first list. Anyway i understand that dataproperty and datasource are important to make this work.

Comment: i've done some change on my query, it seems to work if i put "FaultCodeByOP" in my select query. But then i have an exception : dataError event "SystemArgument.Exception value of datagridviewcomboboxcell isn't valid". After 10 click on "Ok" it show the right value in my combobox but then the message appear more.